# How not to create a "cron-out" log file?

Tags: node.js, pm2

When I run pm2, it creates two `cron-out` and `cron-error` files in the logs folder. How to not create these files when starting pm2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Generate Configuration

```
pm2 ecosystem
```

This will generate following file `(ecosystem.config.js)` ,pass `error_file: "/dev/null"` to not to generate pm2 logs

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: "app",
    script: "./app.js",
    error_file: "/dev/null"  
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: "development",
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: "production",
    }
  }]
}

pm2 [start|restart|stop|delete] ecosystem.config.js
```

This is the link I followed -http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/

> Or Shortest Way

```
pm2 start app /dev/null
```